# Loading GridView on scrolling down

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql

I have a UserControl which is a nested GridView (facebook like wall), i want to load posts on scrolling down. I am following this article..
[CLICK ME](http://www.go4coding.com/post/2011/04/11/Auto-loading-content-on-page-scroll-in-aspnet-using-jquery.aspx)

The problem is that this method is using the first column's last row to get the last productid 
something like this

```
var lastProductId = $("#GridViewUserScraps tr:last").children("td:first").html();
```

But in my case i am not displaying any id in any of the columns of the UserControl's GridView though i have a ScrapId column(primary key) in database. How can i load Posts on scrolling down? how can i make it work?

My UserControl:

```
<div id="divProducts" style="height:700px;overflow:auto">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUserScraps" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                GridLines="None" Width="100%" ShowHeader="False" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#A5A5A5"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataKeyNames="ScrapId" OnRowCommand="GridViewRowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Load More</asp:LinkButton>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='<%#getUserHREF(Container.DataItem)%>'>
                                            <img align="middle" src='<%#getSRC(Container.DataItem)%>' border="0" width="50px" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div align="justify">
                                <b>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"firstname")%>
                                    <div>

         <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenLastProductID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
    </div>
                                </b>
                                <br />
                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Message")%>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("url") %>' style="max-width:500px;" />
                            </div>
                            <span class="SmallBlackText">Posted On: &nbsp;</span>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSendDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SendDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" 
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 
                                CommandName="LikeCmd">Like</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server">unlike</asp:LinkButton>--%>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/thumbsup.png" Height="20px"
                                Width="20px" CommandName="like" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>' />
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnklike" EventName="Click" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Controls_GetUserScraps.abc((int)Eval("ScrapId")) %>' />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            <%--<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# WebPageName.StaticMethodName((int)Eval("ScrapId")) %>' />--%>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'
                                CommandName="unlike" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/thumbsdown.png" Width="20px" />
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkunlike" EventName="Click" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Controls_GetUserScraps.xyz((int)Eval("ScrapId")) %>'></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkcomment" runat="server">Comment</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkviewall" runat="server" CommandName="viewall" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'>View All</asp:LinkButton>
                            <br />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Panel ID="Pnlchildgrid" runat="server">
                                <asp:GridView ID="childgrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="childgrid_RowCommand"
                                    Style="width: 450px; float: right;">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <table align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a href='<%#getUserHREF(Container.DataItem)%>'>
                                                                <img align="middle" src='<%#getSRC(Container.DataItem)%>' border="0" width="30px" /></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <div align="justify">
                                                    <b>
                                                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "firstname")%></b><br />
                                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "commentmsg")%>
                                                    <br />
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="SmallBlackText">Posted On: &nbsp;</span>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSendDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SendDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </span>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" Height="20" Width="20" CommandName="childlike"
                                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("commentid")%>' ImageUrl="~/Images/thumbsup.png" />
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Controls_GetUserScraps.abc1((int)Eval("commentid")) %>' />
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("commentid")%>'
                                                    CommandName="childunlike" Height="20" ImageUrl="~/Images/thumbsdown.png" Width="20" />
                                                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Controls_GetUserScraps.xyz1((int)Eval("commentid")) %>'></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <%--  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkcomment" runat="server">Comment11111</asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                                <br />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomment" runat="server" Width="500px" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Comment" CommandName="comment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>' />
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

Comment: the query is returning id but i think the above code is taking id from html which is being displayed on the page

Comment: did u show id in ur page

Comment: no i am not showing id on the page and i dont even want to show it .

Comment: what is value coming in lastProductId now..alert it and check it....show code of ur grid view too..

Comment: It seems that i am having trouble implementing it when its in UserControl. I tried implementing the example in the article inside a UserControl and i found that no rows were being added on scrolling

Comment: write alert(lastProductId ) just after that line ur assigning....value and tell what value it show

Comment: sorry u want the way to get next data on page without...have product id on the page that is what ur concern right

Comment: i can not whats ur real problem ...u can not implement this or u want rows without having id on ur page please make claer

Comment: @AmitSingh please download the sample attached with that article. Its working fine. Try to convert it in UserControl. It wont work. I think if i can make it work in a usercontrol then my problem would be solved easily. 
Have a Look at this ..
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/576804/LoadingplusGridViewplusRowsplusonplusScrollplusDow

Comment: @AmitSingh right now i am just trying to make a UserControl out of that article.

Comment: hi Arbaaz  try this link [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-on-demand-data-in-GridView-on-scroll-using-ASPNet-and-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)  link 2[link](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/)

Comment: @Chandruvelan i found those links before but it uses XML and i have no clue about XML